# how to do boost perl regex matching having support for case sensitive/insensitive

Tags: c++, regex, perl, boost

I want to implement following perl evaluation in boost regex or any other alternative in cpp.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex_pattern = "/^rst/i";
my $name = "rst";
my $match;
my $tmpRegExp = "\$match = (\$name =~ $regex_pattern);";
eval ($tmpRegExp);

if(!$match) {
    print "not matched\n";
} else {
    print "matched\n";
}
```

*Perl coutput*

```
% perl perl_regex.pl 
matched
```

I tried by below sample code

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string regex_pattern("/^rst/i");
    std::string name("rst");
    boost::regex regex_expr(regex_pattern, boost::regex::perl);
    bool match = boost::regex_search(name, regex_expr);
    if(match)
       std::cout << "matched" << std::endl;
    else
       std::cout << "not matched" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

*C++ Output*

```
% g++ boost_regex.cpp -l boost_regex  
% ./a.out  
not matched
```

But this is not working as expected. I expected "**matched**" shall be the result for boost version also. this regex_pattern is a perl regex user variable. 
Can someone help, where is the mistake?

Comment: All this Perl code does is assign the return value of the pattern match to the `$match` variable. It's either `1` or the empty string `""`. There's nothing Perl-specific in the pattern. It has a beginning of string anchor and a `/i` flag. Those are both very generic and should be implemented in any regex engine. What's your problem here? What do you expect to happen? What is really happening? Please [edit] your question and be more specific.

Comment: @simbabque edited the question with more details.

Comment: What does that `eval` in the Perl code have to do with it? I have no clue what this _boost_ thing is, but I guess your pattern is wrong. If this _boost_ regex implementation has a debug mode, turn it on, and look at the output.

Comment: eval is the function to evaluate the expression. Boost is the extension C++ library to implement advanced features like regex. Pattern is correct only, you can check by running the programs. https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html

Comment: The `eval` has nothing to do with the pattern match. The `=~` operator is doing the pattern match, and the `m//` constructs a pattern. `eval` in the way you are using it is doing a [string eval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eval). You do not have a string eval in your CPP code, and you don't need one if all you want to do is a pattern match.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this example in the documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/example/snippets/regex_match_example.cpp) of the Boost regex feature, the pattern should not have slashes around it, and you cannot pass flags to the pattern within the pattern string like you would with the pattern creation operator `m//` in Perl.

```
regex expression("^([0-9]+)(\\-| |$)(.*)$");
```

[Boost's documentation about PCRE](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html) says that by default, the pattern is case-sensitive. This supports my assumption that you cannot pass a flag like `/i` within the pattern itself. Instead, you need to pass it as a flag as the second argument to the pattern constructor as shown in the [SYNOPSIS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.synopsis).

```
// e2 a case insensitive Perl regular expression:
boost::regex e2(my_expression, boost::regex::perl|boost::regex::icase);
```

A full list of those flags for PCRE within Boost is available [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/syntax_option_type/syntax_option_type_perl.html). Note that not all of these map to actual modifier flags that can be on `m//` or `s///` in current Perls as described in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers). That's because [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) is **not** Perl, but rather the *Perl Compatible Regex Engine*.

Comment: I got all of this from just reading the documentation, which I googled.

Comment: And it's all good.  The `boost` is a major and very respected set of very well rounded libraries, many of which practically extend the language and  often fortell what is getting into next standards.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Standard Regex mechanism since C++11.
I personally would prefer this over boost or any other third party library. Of course that's only my own opinion.

If you want to use the utilities provided with C++11 you could do the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  std::string input = "rst";
  std::regex regex_pattern("^rst", std::regex_constants::icase); // use ::icase to make the matching case insensitive like /i in perl

  if ( std::regex_match(input, regex_pattern) )
  {
    std::cout << "matched!\n";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "not matched!\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```